# How to create a new database with the PostGIS extensions

Tags: postgresql, postgis

[image]

I installed PostGis in the docker, in the standard database there are all the necessary extensions, but when creating a new one there are none, what do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already has the libraries installed in the system, just connect to the database `geo` and execute the create extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis
```

Keep in mind that you have to additionally `CREATE EXTENSION` in the database you want, unless you create the database based on a template that already has PostGIS installed.

From the [`PostGIS documentation`](https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#install_short_version) :

> Once postgis is installed, it needs to be enabled in each individual
>   database you want to use it in.